# How to manually trigger a built-in action in QuillJS?

Tags: javascript, quill

I am using **QuillJS v2.0.0-dev.4** and I am trying to condense the toolbar. In other words, I would like to group several default actions under one dropdown. Here is the screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

When an option is selected in the dropdown, this custom method gets called

```
Dropdown.onSelect = (label, value, quill) => {
    switch(true){
        case /^h1$/.test(value):  
                    //some code needed
                 break;
        case /^h2$/.test(value):  break;
        case /^h5$/.test(value):  break;
    }
};
```

Does anyone know how to trigger the default `H1` action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else needs this, here is the anwer

`quill.format('header','h1');`